# How does one calculate the minimum & average by row over multiple columns in Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, average, min

I am having a hard time writing DAX to calculate the average of aggregated averages by row and column.  I also, am not having luck writing DAX to calculate the minimum of the aggregated averages by row.  This is how my data is structured:

[image: Raw Data]

These tables represent what the data looks like aggreated (Table 1) and what the desired output is (Table 2).

[image: Desired Results]

Can anyone help?  Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following three **Measures**:

```
Avg by Date = 
  AVERAGEX(
    DISTINCT('YourTable'[Department]),
    CALCULATE(AVERAGE(YourTable[Value]))
  )


Min Avg by Date = 
  MINX(
    DISTINCT('YourTable'[Department]),
    CALCULATE(AVERAGE(YourTable[Value]))
  )


Avg of Avg by Date = 
  CALCULATE(
    AVERAGEX(
      DISTINCT('YourTable'[Date]),
      [Avg by Date]
    ),
    ALLSELECTED('YourTable'[Date])
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! Very helpful. I also used your formula to get the maximum and then I was able to calculate the avg range. However, now I need to do an average of the average range I just calculated. Any chance you can help with that? Thanks! – 
Adam Meyer

Comment: If I understood correctly, replace `[Avg by Date]` with `DIVIDE([Min Avg by Date] + [Max Avg by Date], 2)`, or replace with the new measure you created.

Answer (score 0):

```
FinalAverageByDate = 
VAR SummaryTable =
    SUMMARIZE(
        'YourTable', 
        [Date],
        [Department],
        "AverageValue", 
         AVERAGE([Value])
    )
RETURN
        SUMMARIZE(
            SummaryTable,
            [Date],
            "AverageValue", 
            AVERAGE([AverageValue])
        )
// Just create a new table with this code)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Power Query

[image]

M code for this is

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ddBLCsAgDATQu7guNH/1LNL7X6OSpIsG3AjyGCdxrYbtaqA32k1AvC8MsE8zas+1GlU25z7ZmQ/pGWlJ7h9LpHU4a2VKVmc7pG069+Tx7+4izqOyBndznpXzcQ5GSJ9lNozNEKtnO0M4HRxjeMyfIyj9mP1S/dsOw/XgtPufFw==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Id = _t, Date = _t, Department = _t, Value = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Id", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"Department", Int64.Type}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column1" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Department", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Department", type text}}, "en-US")[Department]), "Department", "Value", List.Sum),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Pivoted Column1", {"Date"}, {{"Dept200", each List.Sum([200]), type nullable number}, {"Dept300", each List.Sum([300]), type nullable number}, {"Dept400", each List.Sum([400]), type nullable number}, {"Dept500", each List.Sum([500]), type nullable number}, {"Dept600", each List.Sum([600]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each List.Min({[Dept200],[Dept300],[Dept400],[Dept500],[Dept600]})),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", "MinByDate"}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Custom", each List.Average({[Dept200],[Dept300],[Dept400],[Dept500],[Dept600]})),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom1",{{"Custom", "AvgByDate"}}),
    AvgofAvg= Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Custom", each List.Average(#"Renamed Columns1"[AvgByDate])),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(AvgofAvg,{{"Custom", "AvgOfAvgByDate"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns2"
```